# EF migration in VScode

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-migrations, blazor-webassembly

I tried to do a migration with `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` and I obtained the message  :
`Build started...`
`Build succeeded.`
`System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')`

appsettings.json

> "ConnectionsStrings":{
> "DefaultConnection":"Data Source=(localdb)\LocalDBApp1;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
> },

Startup.cs

> services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

Have you an idea how I can solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `ConnectionStrings` instead of `ConnectionsStrings` (extra "s")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a typo, try with `ConnectionStrings` instead of `ConnectionsStrings` in your `appsettings.json`.

Comment: Hi it's OK with ConnectionStrings. Thanks!